# Using a WISON OR200 in web application ( MVC )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, fingerprint

Few days ago i bought a WISON OR200 sensor for a web system  that i am developing.

I used the SDK that sent to me the enterprise and was been testing in a window application and worked fine but i need it into a web application and i don´t know how to do it..

this is the windows form application:

```
WisSensorN WisObj = new WisSensorN();  // instance of wison object
```

objects in form:

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button Enroll;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button Identify;
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox FingerPic;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button Stop;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox Status;
```

Load method()    //Open() .DataEvent and SetDisplay are needed for the fingerprint

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WisObj.Open();
        WisObj.DataEvent += new _IWisSensorNEvents_DataEventEventHandler(WisObj_DataEvent);
        WisObj.SetDisplay((int)FingerPic.Handle); 
         // i can´t do WisObj.SetDisplay((int)FingerPic.Handle) on mvc web app
         // because i can't get FingerPic object from view.
    }

    private void WisObj_DataEvent(WisSensorNLibLib.DATA data, string str)
    {
        switch (data)
        {
            case DATA.DATA_ENROLL:
                // save the base 64 string of finger image
                break;

            case DATA.DATA_IDENTIFY_CAPTURE:
                //validation
                break;

            case DATA.DATA_VERIFY_CAPTURE:
                break;
        }
    }


private void Enroll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       WisObj.StartEnroll(); // it used for save the fingerprint
    }

private void Identify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WisObj.IdentifyCapture(); 
       // it used to activate the sensor. When i did this on controller action,
       // nothing happen. This is because the property setDisplay was not set 
    }
```

Any suggestions?
What can i do?

I asked to the company where i bought the fingerprint reader if have a SDK for web applications and never answered.

Help please!

Thnxs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on a very wrong path. You can't simply use a device from a browser. The HTML/javascript 'application' that runs in the browser cannot connect to any local resource like I/O ports or Windows events. You will need special techniques, like ActiveX or Java applet to communicate with a device on a client machine.

Whether your website is MVC or plain ASP.NET or even PHP is irrelevant. If you don't know what ActiveX (and alumni) is used for and what drawbacks it has, you should look for a professional who can help you explain the situation and possibly develop a suitable solution.

Comment: I know that this is a web application and is not posible to comunicate with a device on a client machine, but i saw it working!
ok, i will try to find a professional or some activeX.
thank you.